# How to override and localize client-side validation messages for ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: validation, localization, asp.net-mvc-4, client-side, message

I've created custom validators with localized strings which are loaded from my satellite resource assemblies. Now I want to override default MVC messages like "{0} must be a number".

In this article:
http://martinnormark.com/asp-net-mvc-localize-numeric-data-val-number-validation
the author says

> I was browsing through the source code of ASP.NET MVC 4, and found a
>   changeset that looks like will fix this issue. In short, it will be
>   possible to define your own ResourceClassKey, and the MVC framework
>   will use that before using default error messages. Nice!

So I started looking how to use the new features but most of solutions seem outdated and don't work or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

How do I override client side error messages in MVC 4 using resource dll files? 
Does MVC itself always decide which resource assembly to pick or I can somehow force it to pick the one I need for a specific language?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42168/Localizing-ASP-NET-MVC
did not appear in my earlier searches.

The key point was to add the App_GlobalResources folder manually and move resource assemblies there, and only then it picked up our custom messages.

For some reason the App_GlobalResources folder is missing when creating MVC 4 app in Visual Studio 2012 so we assumed that it is not needed any more. But when digging through the MVC source code, we found that MVC is using HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject which looks in App_GlobalResources. Oh, Microsoft, come on, why are you doing this... we spent three days looking for various complex solutions just because you threw out that folder from the latest MVC version.